# How can I convert do-while loop to for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, do-while

I am new to programming and wanted to know how can I convert this below do-while loop to for

```
$total=0;
$count=10;
do {
  echo ($count. "<br>");
  $count = $count - 2;
  $total = $total + $count;
} while($count < 1)

echo $total;
```

Comment: do you know your `do-while` loop works just once?

Comment: Don't you mean `while ($count > 1)`? Anyway, [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) should help.

Comment: @FatemehNB yes i know that output is 10 8 and its definitely $count < 1

Comment: @Jeto its $count < 1

Comment: @RichardDoe Your loop has no purpose then since it won't ever iterate more than once.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean `While ($count > 1)`, then try below :

```
for ($count = 10 ; $count > 1 ; $count-2) {
    echo ($count. "<br>");
    $total = $total + ($count -2);
}
```

Comment: Think you need something like `$count-=2` in the last param of the `for()`

Comment: That is what is confusing me, It is $count < 1

Comment: If your while condition is correct, so it seems that loop is useless here.